# What is the difference between a widget and a panel in Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, panel

Also, is the paintComponent() method used to paint a widget or a panel?

Comment: Nothing. A widget is a component. Yes `paintComponent` is part of the process for painting

Comment: A panel is a widget but a widget isn't necessarily a panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Panel` : Abstract base class for all panels, which are widgets that can contain other widgets. The hierarchy of `Class Panel` is [Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html).

`Widget` :The base class for the majority of user-interface objects. Widget adds support for receiving events from the browser and being added directly to panels. Read more about Widget [Here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html).